# uploading using array_chuck csv not working

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

can any know how to fix this problem
the ff. code must be in csv format

sample.csv

[one] [two] [three] =1st row
[four] [five] [six] = 2nd row

i try to split the ff. data with the ff code and i got this result

```
 print_r( array_chunk(fgetcsv($handle,1000,","),3) );

  Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
             [0] => one
             [1] => two
             [2] => three four
          ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
             [0] => five
             [1] => six
          ) 
      )
```

i want to be the result must be like this

```
  Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
             [0] => one
             [1] => two
             [2] => three
          ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
             [0] => four
             [1] => five
             [2] => six
          ) 
      )
```

Comment: show result of  `print_r(fgetcsv($handle,1000,","));`

Comment: Array
     (
         [0] => one
         [1] => two
         [2] => three
     four
         [3] => five
         [4] => six
     )